# Verb used for "being in a class"

Tags: grammar, verbs

I'm new to Japanese language. I was looking for a way to ask "what class are you in?" or similar (not sure if that's the right way to translate it to Japanese, but the idea is to ask him what class is he taking in this precise moment, considering we're in different schools and we're texting).

So far I've found threads here in Stack Exchange but they refer to the verb "attend" or "to be registered" rather than what I want to say.

I ended up with the sentence:

> nani no kurasu wa anata ga imasu ka (sorry no hiragana on my computer's keyboard)

He understand what I meant, but I'm not sure that was right. What's the right way to ask this?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, by "taking" do you mean "currently sitting in", or just "enrolled in"?

Comment: currently sitting in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say something like

> - 今の{授業・クラス}は？
> - 今なんの{授業・クラス}？
> - 今出席の{授業・クラス}は？

Comment: Since we're (my friend and I) trying to use words we both know, is it correct to use `クラス` instead? like: `今のクラスは？` ?

Comment: Oh, I assumed you were texting a Japanese person.  But yes, `クラス` is fine too.